# MySQL NOW() + 14 or CURDATE() + 14 in Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to add in new column a date = 14 from today or NOW() + 14

Here is the current query:

```
"INSERT INTO  `client_subscription` ( `start_date`,`status`,`sent_signals`,`client_id`,`subscription_type_id`, `last_update`, `edited_by` )
    VALUES (NOW(),'active',0," + last_insert_id + ", 5, now(), '0' )";
```

We have an `end_date` column as well after start_date and now its empty. I need to make this query put the end date to be after 14 days(or other number) so to make the trial subscription.

Here what I wrote:

```
"INSERT INTO  `client_subscription` ( `start_date`,`end_date`,`status`,`sent_signals`,`client_id`,`subscription_type_id`, `last_update`, `edited_by` )
    VALUES (NOW(),CURDATE() + 14,'active',0," + last_insert_id + ", 5, now(), '0' )";
```

Comment: `NOW()` will produce a timestamp, `CURDATE()` will only produce a date. Ask your business stakeholders if they want a timestamp or a date for the trial subscription end

Comment: can you help me to be a timestamp? thanks!

Comment: How about `NOW() + INTERVAL 14 DAY`? Either a date, datetime or timestamp should (probably) work

Comment: @Corion now() returns the current date and time as datetime, not as a timestamp. Otherwise, I agree, this is a business decision, not a programming one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL +14 DAY)` like in next example:

```
INSERT INTO
    client_subscription (start_date, end_date, status, sent_signals, client_id, subscription_type_id, last_update, edited_by )
VALUES
    (NOW(), DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL +14 DAY), 'active', 0, "" + last_insert_id + "", 5, NOW(), '0')
```